# How to show only digit keys in keyboard windows phone 7?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, textbox, windows-phone

I am developing a windows phone app and am new in wp7 development. I am using a text box to enter amount of a product. Only digits are allowed to enter in to that field. So my need is to display digits (0 to 9) in the keypad. How can I do this ?.. Please help.

I tried the following code

```
<TextBox Name="textBox1" Width="200" Height="100" Text="0.00" TextAlignment="Right">
            <TextBox.InputScope>
                <InputScope>
                    <InputScopeName NameValue="CurrencyAmount"  />
                </InputScope>
            </TextBox.InputScope>
        </TextBox>
```

But still it showing the keyboard below.

[image]

Comment: Just tried the above code and the correct, digits only, keyboard is shown. Try to reboot your computer/test in a different project and if is still reproducible i would suggest to repair/reinstall WP7 SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        <TextBox.InputScope>
            <InputScope>
                <InputScopeName NameValue="Number"  />
            </InputScope>
        </TextBox.InputScope>
```

you just need 0~9

so += the keydown event of textblock

and use these code

```
        switch (e.Key)
        {
            case Key.D0:
            case Key.D1:
            case Key.D2:
            case Key.D3:
            case Key.D4:
            case Key.D5:
            case Key.D6:
            case Key.D7:
            case Key.D8:
            case Key.D9:
            case Key.Back:
            case Key.Delete:
                break;
            default:
                e.Handled = true;
                return;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use *InputScope* property on the TextBox.

For example: `<TextBox InputScope="Number"/>`

or : `<TextBox InputScope="CurrencyAmount"/>`

For more information you can look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/gg521152%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).
You can find all the possible values for InputScope [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputscopenamevalue%28VS.95%29.aspx).

You can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh393998%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) visually how all the input scopes look like.

Also be sure that you'll validate the input in the code behind, for example user might have a physical keyboard on the device.

Comment: Hi. I did as u suggested. But this showing the number mode first time. But the user can switch to alphabets by pressing "abcd" button on keyboard.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for helping me. I tried as you suggested adrian. Please see my updated question above. still the same problem.